# Python: JSON to object Unicode issue

Tags: python, unicode

I am using the following to convert the response result to object:

```
response = requests.get(url=request_url)
myobjs = json.loads(response.text, object_hook=lambda d: Myobj(**d))
return myobjs
```

and

```
class Myobj(object):
    def __init__(self, id, display):
        self.id = str(id)
        self.name = str(display)
```

Sample JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id": "92cbb711-7e4d-417a-9530-f1850d9bc687",
        "display": "010lf.com",
    },
    {
        "id": "1060864a-a3a5-40c2-aa94-651fe2d10ae9",
        "display": "010lm.com",
    }
]
```

It works well until one day, one of the field display in the returned JSON contains unicode value for example:

```
"display": "관악저널.kr"
```

It will give the below error:

```
File "mycode.py", line 5, in __init__
    self.name = str(display)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I would have thought the str() function would handle the unicode code string properly.

What is that I am missing?

I try to change the line from

```
self.name = str(display)
```

to

```
self.name = display
```

It seems to do the trick but I wanna check if I am doing it correctly and efficiently?

Comment: Are you using Python 2.7?

Comment: str() will work for ascii characters that happened to have been stored in unicode strings.  This means that self.name is now a Unicode object, not a str object. It will work, but only if your other code handles Unicode objects.

Comment: yes, 2.7.13 @ivo

Comment: @StevenYong If you switch to 3.x, all these problems will go away.

Comment: @ivo, what is in 3 that fixes that?

Comment: @KevinHirst, you are right i have to go through all my codes to make sure the rest of the codes can handle that field properly, is there a way to still use str() for this?

Comment: @StevenYong in Python 3, all strings can be unicode so you never have to worry about this stuff.

Comment: You can use str(display.encode('utf-8', errors='ignore'))  But you may lose data that way, if you are getting Korean characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json` returns the strings as Unicode.  So either store them as Unicode (the correct solution) or encode them in UTF-8.  Note that `str()` converts Unicode strings to bytes strings with the `ascii` codec, so doesn't work with non-ASCII-only Unicode strings.

```
#!python2
#coding:utf8
import json

text = '''\
[
    {
        "id": "92cbb711-7e4d-417a-9530-f1850d9bc687",
        "display": "관악저널.kr"
    },
    {
        "id": "1060864a-a3a5-40c2-aa94-651fe2d10ae9",
        "display": "010lm.com"
    }
]'''

class Myobj(object):
    def __init__(self, id, display):
        self.id = id # or id.encode('utf8')
        self.name = display # or display.encode('utf8')
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'MyObj({self.id!r},{self.name!r})'.format(self=self)

myobjs = json.loads(text, object_hook=lambda d: Myobj(**d))
print(myobjs)
```

Output:

```
[MyObj(u'92cbb711-7e4d-417a-9530-f1850d9bc687',u'\uad00\uc545\uc800\ub110.kr'),
 MyObj(u'1060864a-a3a5-40c2-aa94-651fe2d10ae9',u'010lm.com')]
```